# Assigning two lists as each others equals

Tags: python, list

I was just trying to write a code in Python for Euler Problem 15 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=15), concerning Lattice Paths.

I wanted to write something which would return (1,2,1), (1, 3, 3, 1), (1, 4, 6, 4, 1) etc. I wrote the following:

```
lijst = [1,1]
temp = [1,1]
for a in range(2,21):
    temp.append(1)
        for b in range(1,a):
        temp[b] = lijst[b-1] + lijst[b]
    lijst = temp
    print a, lijst
```

To my surprise, this didn't work. At the start of the second 'for'-loop, somehow the append doesn't only work on 'temp', but also on 'lijst'. I got the code working by changing:

```
lijst = temp
```

into:

```
lijst = [a for a in temp]
```

What's the problem hear? Am I missing something out on the behaviour of lists?

Thanks!

Comment: What you're missing isn't the behavior of lists, but the behavior of variables and values in general. When you do `lijst = temp`, that just makes `lijst` into another name for the same value that `temp` is a name for. So, since they're both naming the same value, changing that value under one name is obviously changing the same value under a different name. If you want to make a copy in Python, you have to explicitly make a copy (although you can do it a lot more simply with `temp[:]` or `list(temp)` instead of `[a for a in temp]`).

Comment: Also see [this blog post](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder. (The presentation linked at the top is probably even better, but I haven't viewed it myself…)

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate response! Will watch the presentation, great link.

Comment: While you're at it, bookmark [the blog index](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/tag/python.html) and skim it when you have time later; this definitely isn't the only case where he manages to take something confusing and make it obvious, while our official SO answer is only so-so…